# ZFS 0.7 version in Centos 7.6

Tags: centos, centos-7, zfs

i am trying to install zfs in my centos 7.6 with kernel  3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 using this guide:
https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/RHEL-and-CentOS
and doing a

```
yum install http://download.zfsonlinux.org/epel/zfs-release.el7_6.noarch.rpm
```

but when i tried to install it install 0.6.5.9-1.el7.centos version, and when i do a

```
yum list zfs
```

it said:ACA

```
zfs.x86_64        0.6.5.9-1.el7.centos        zfs
```

like the only option, and this version have problem loading the module so i want use a newer one but i can only see this one, Could you help me thit this?